# How to check if LSI20320IE is working without LTO TAPE in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, pci, scsi

I have done a `lspci -vv` to check if my Driver for the LSI20320IE SCSI Controller ( [Data-Sheet](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/12352395) ) is correct installed. (The LSI-drivers are from here [MPTLINUX_RHEL4_SLES9_PH14-3.13.04.00-2.zip](https://www.driverguide.com/driver/company/LSI_Logic/index.html) and I did running `alien` on terminal command prompt in the directory `pkg-2/dkms` to convert the two rpms into `Debian` packages and then `gdebi <deb-package-name>`  to install the two `DEBIAN`-Packages)  :  It sheems so that this was fine, but how can I test if the SCSI controller is working. I have no LTO2 Drive yet, but soon. A HP LTO Ultrium 960 should be running on my **Ubuntu 20.04LTS** PC.

My output of `lspci -vv` is a follows:

```
05:08.0 SCSI storage controller: Broadcom / LSI 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev c1)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company SC11Xe Ultra320 Single Channel PCIe x4 SCSI Host Bus Adapter (412911-B21)
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 32 (4000ns min, 1500ns max), Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 26
Region 0: I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
Region 1: Memory at f5720000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
Region 3: Memory at f5700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
Expansion ROM at f5600000 [disabled] [size=1M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: mptspi
Kernel modules: mptspi
```

Thanks for any useful advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn’t need to install any particular driver, the `mptspi` driver is included in the default kernel on Ubuntu. You can tell it loaded correctly for your card based on

```
Kernel driver in use: mptspi
```

To verify that the SCSI HBA is recognised, install the `lsscsi` package and run `lsscsi -H`; this should list `mptspi` as one of the hosts on your system.

Once you connect a tape drive to your HBA, you should see it enumerated during the system boot, and it should show up with a plain `lsscsi`; you should also see `/dev/st*` devices corresponding to the tape drive.

Comment: @Stephen_Kitt Thank you very much